# I cant find out the right solution for jquery function

Tags: jquery

I tried different things. but cant figure it out. I have to change the line (var total = (Persons) * 2. Instead of "2" i Want to have a $ ($number) thats a value from database.

```
 function updateProduct1()
   {

    var Persons = parseFloat($("#dare_price1").val());
    if (!isNaN(Persons))
    {
        var total = (Persons) * 2;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount1").val(total);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#total_price_amount1").val("");
    }
    updateTotal();
}
```

**EDIT**:

I get the $number from the database table

```
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = "2" ') as $row) {  

    $article = $row['article'];
    $number = $row['number'];
    }
```

I have somewhere the line:

```
<td class="style11" id="number_id"><?php echo $number ?></td>
```

May be it is a bit clearly now

Comment: do you have any object variable associated for database variable?

Comment: I can't see `$number` in your code

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve], asking to get a value from the _database_ is unclear, too broad and does not considered as a valid attempt

Comment: `$dbh->query` return result object, you need to use fetch to get actual rows from db. Check this https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 0):

If by `$number` you are referring to a php variable, then you are confusing something. You can not access a `php` variable from `jQuery` just like that. You will need to make sure the value from `php` is displayed somewhere, so you can grab it from `jQuery`. Alternatively, you can request the value by AJAX and use it inside the function.